# Why is vector data not saved permanently in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I'm using QGIS 2.2.0.  I add a vector to a vector layer and save the file.  After I reopen the .qgs file, the new vector is not shown.

(1) Click 'Toggle Editing'

[image]

(2) Click 'Add Feature' and draw a polyline.

[image]

(3) Click 'Save Layer Edits'

[image]

(4) Click 'Save'

[image]

Comment: What type of file is my_line?

Comment: It is a vector layer created using `layer =  QgsVectorLayer('LineString', 'my line' , 'memory')` and `QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([layer])`

Comment: An in-memory layer is not persisted. You need to save it as a shapefile or other file system type. They are intended only as a temporary storage for processing etc.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson Thank you very much for the info.  I'm now able to save the vector.

Comment: You're welcome. I'll turn that into an answer in case anyone else encounters this problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In memory layers are temporary, they don't get *saved* when you call *save edits*. They are only intended to be temporary and should be saved as a file system type (like shapefile) if you intend to keep their edits.

You should probably call `QgsVectorLayer::setCoordinateSystem()` on the layer before editing and definitely before saving. All spatial data should have a coordinate system, even if you make it the same as the canvas.